# Dealing with message loops in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I have multiple objects in my app that are both send and receive the same message.  For example: The column order of a grid can be changed when the user drags and drops columns on the grid, when the user uses the grid settings dialog and when the user loads a different report.  So the Grid can both send a "Column Order Changed" message and as well as receive the message.

Is there a way to prevent the Grid from getting its own messages back?  So when the user drags a column around, the Grid sends a "Column Order Changed" message to all interested listeners,  but I don't want the Grid to then get a call back on its subscription.  I could use a predicate and embed some sender information in the message but I wondering if Mvvm Light can handle this scenario itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this overload of the IMessenger Register method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers a recipient for a type of message TMessage.
///             The action parameter will be executed when a corresponding
///             message is sent. See the receiveDerivedMessagesToo parameter
///             for details on how messages deriving from TMessage (or, if TMessage is an interface,
///             messages implementing TMessage) can be received too.
/// 
/// <para>
/// Registering a recipient does not create a hard reference to it,
///             so if this recipient is deleted, no memory leak is caused.
/// </para>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessage">The type of message that the recipient registers
///             for.</typeparam><param name="recipient">The recipient that will receive
///             the messages.</param><param name="token">A token for a messaging
///             channel. If a recipient registers using a token, and a sender sends
///             a message using the same token, then this message will be delivered to
///             the recipient. Other recipients who did not use a token when
///             registering (or who used a different token) will not get the message.
///             Similarly, messages sent without any token, or with a different
///             token, will not be delivered to that recipient.</param><param name="receiveDerivedMessagesToo">If true, message types deriving from
///             TMessage will also be transmitted to the recipient. For example, if a SendOrderMessage
///             and an ExecuteOrderMessage derive from OrderMessage, registering for OrderMessage
///             and setting receiveDerivedMessagesToo to true will send SendOrderMessage
///             and ExecuteOrderMessage to the recipient that registered.
/// 
/// <para>
/// Also, if TMessage is an interface, message types implementing TMessage will also be
///             transmitted to the recipient. For example, if a SendOrderMessage
///             and an ExecuteOrderMessage implement IOrderMessage, registering for IOrderMessage
///             and setting receiveDerivedMessagesToo to true will send SendOrderMessage
///             and ExecuteOrderMessage to the recipient that registered.
/// </para>
/// </param><param name="action">The action that will be executed when a message
///             of type TMessage is sent.</param>
void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, object token, bool receiveDerivedMessagesToo, Action<TMessage> action);
```

Note:

> A token for a messaging channel. If a recipient registers using a token, and a sender sends a message using the same token, then this message will be delivered to the recipient. Other recipients who did not use a token when registering (or who used a different token) will not get the message. Similarly, messages sent without any token, or with a different token, will not be delivered to that recipient.

What you can do is have the other registers of that message to register with a token, then when the grid sends a message send with that token. the grid's registration should not include the token.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  But the issue with using tokens for this, is every publisher would need its own token, and every subscriber would need to subscribe for each token other than its own.  This becomes pretty messy and difficult to maintain the more publishers you add to the system.  In my case I have 3 objects that can both send and receive and fourth that just receives.  I could exented Mvvm Light so when you send a message you can pass an object and if it is the same as the recipient object that was used when registering then the message isn't delivered.

Comment: @MattS Perhaps your grid needs to publish a different type of message, a type that it does not subscribe to. There must be a difference since the messages need to be handled differently.

Comment: Every publisher would have their own flavor of the same message then and they would all need to subscribe to the different flavors.

Comment: @MattS How about intercept the grid column move and e.Cancel it, but still send the message. Then have the handler do the move, just like it would from anywhere else.

Comment: how about adding GetHashCode() as an ID to the message. If it's your ID, ignore it. Or add an instance to your object in the message (e.g. object Sender { get; set; }, if it's you ignore it.

Comment: @kenny, Yeah, thats what I'm going to do, I was hoping there might have been something I've been missing in Mvvm Light that handled this scenario, but I don't think so.